# Pass arguments to pushnamed but in receiver widget give null in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I sent data from one widget to another widget value is entered but when I go to next widget or receiver widget it gives me the null value I tried all answers of s.o.f but nothing works. I am using stable channel 2.1.

sender widget

```
         routes: {
    '/result': (context) => LoginScreen(),
  },

      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/result',arguments: {
                'weight':count,
                'height':heights,
              });
```

receiver widget:

```
              final  argument= ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
print(argument['weight']);
```

thats error i got at receiver widget "type null is not a subtype of type map in type cast"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material App

```
  routes: {
    '/result': (context) => LoginScreen(),
  }
```

Navigation

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/result', arguments: {
    'weight': count,
    'height': heights,
 });
```

LoginScreen()

```
final argument = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
print(argument['weight']);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the routes page, try this:

```
TestPage.routeName: (context) => TestPage(),
```

While calling, try this:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, TestPage.routeName)
```